# SignalR throwing JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm new to signalr. I've started an MVC 4.0 application, out of the box, and wired up my signalr JavaScript on the Index View. When I click either the Register or Login buttons, signalr throws a JavaScript error.

```
Unhandled exception at line 11, column 10700 in http://localhost:49172/Scripts/jquery.signalR-   0.5.1.min.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'src': object is null or undefined
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the extent of my code:

```
$(function () {    
    var blasht = $.connection.blashtHub;    
    blasht.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '');
    };     

    $("#blashtIt").click(function () {
        var control = $('#blashtText');
        var control2 = $('#hiddenUserId');
        // Call the chat method on the server  
        blasht.send(control2.val(), control.val());
        control.val('');
    });

    blasht.updateTopTen = function (message) {
        //add code to update the top user's list
    };

    // Start the connection   
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

As suggested I dropped the min and here is where it is crashing, on the frame.sc = src; line.

```
reconnect: function (connection) {
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    var frame = connection.frame,
    src = transportLogic.getUrl(connection, that.name, true) + "&frameId=" + connection.frameId;
               connection.log("Upating iframe src to '" + src + "'.");
               frame.src = src;
            }, connection.reconnectDelay);
        },
```

SignalR, not me, is invoking this reconnect function. Obviously, that is how it maintains a connection with the server.

Comment: You'll have to show your code, and in particular the code that sets the `src` property as well as the code that gets whatever object you're setting the `src` property on.

Comment: This particular bug was fixed, so upgrade SignalR :)

Answer (score 9):

The is a bug in the current version of SignalR for the "Forever-Frame" implementation, which is the one that IE9 uses:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/446

A workaround is to force SignalR not to use Forever-Frame transport (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client). 
So change

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

to

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] });
```

Comment: Yea that bug was fixed. So just update your script and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, and without your having shown any code, I'd have to guess that you have code that looks like this:

```
foo.src = someValue;
```

...where `foo` is `null` or `undefined`. Which begs the question of ***why*** is `foo` `null` or `undefined`, but without more context, it's impossible to say. Stepping through with the IE8+ "F12 Developer Tools" may help you pinpoint it.

---

*(Update after code was posted)*

I'm guessing that the line causing the error is `frame.src = src;`. Reformatting that code with consistent indentation:

```
reconnect: function (connection) {
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var frame = connection.frame,
            src = transportLogic.getUrl(connection, that.name, true) + "&frameId=" + connection.frameId;
        connection.log("Upating iframe src to '" + src + "'.");
        frame.src = src;  // <=== Presumably this is the line failing
    }, connection.reconnectDelay);
},
```

It would appear that as of the time the delayed function is called, `connection.frame` is `null` or `undefined`. So you'll need to find out why that is. The first thing I'd do is check whether `connection.frame` is `null` or `undefined` when `reconnect` is called, or if it's only later when the delayed function runs (e.g., has something cleared it in the meantime, and if so, why).

Comment: Thanks T.J. but the error isn't in my code, it's in signalr's code. I can show how I'm referencing the JavaScript files, but there isn't much else to show. I was hoping someone else had encountered this.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr.: Surely you're triggering the SignalR code in some way?

Comment: As suggested above, use F12/IE9 to figure out why you're not bringing in all the JavaScript libs you think you are or exactly what else is going on. And drop the .min for dev/debug.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr.: I've added a note to the end of the answer. And regardless of whose code the error is in, you're the one stuck with debugging it. :-) As Rick suggested, use the un-minified copy of SignalR to start with, so you can meaningfully single-step through it, etc. But basically, find out why `connection.frame` is `null`/`undefined` and that should sort it out.